# Play several mp3 files with Jlayer

Tags: java, mp3

I wrote an app to play mp3 files and I have the controls and everything rolling, just a problem that each mp3 file is played individually and I have to trigger the play of a new file.

I want to know how can I tell (pro grammatically) if the player has finished playing a file, so I can move on to the next one?

this is the thread code

```
@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        System.out.println(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        player = new Player(bis);
        player.play();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are looking for: `player.isComplete()` ===> in the context of JLayer api

```
while (!player.isComplete()) {
    //
    //
}
```

There you go: http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html#isComplete%28%29

Hope it helps.